# Non-standard multisig

Tags: multi-signature

I have a question regarding this transaction where the outputs are showing as non-standard but appear to be multi-sigs. This is the first output:

Transaction ID: 54e48e5f5c656b26c3bca14a8c95aa583d07ebe84dde3b7dd4a78f4e4186e713

```
OP_1
e4cf0200067daf13255044462d312e340a25c3a4c3bcc3b6c39f0a322030206f626a0a3c3c2f4c656e6774682033203020522f46696c7465722f466c6174654465
636f64653e3e0a73747265616d0a789cad5c4b8b24b911becfafa8b3a1da292925654253d0d55373f06d61c007e39bbd061f0cde8bffbe25c55b5266f61ab3905d
9ba54728e28bb76a963777fbcfb77fdf96db7d291f93f3e599f7fafcedefb73fffe1f6aff665fdefb77f7c7bfefce6c2fa166e695bdfd6dbcfbfddfef8c3dd5cf9
OP_3
OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

Is there an issue with the public key hashes or the script? I am new to this so sure I am missing something simple.

Thank you

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35959/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP_CHECKMULTISIG is typically preceded by:

- The number of keys (n)
- n public keys (not public key hashes!)
- The number of signatures required (k)

That is not the case here, because the 3 byte arrays that are pushed in between the OP_3 and the OP_1 are not public keys. Public keys are either:

- 33 bytes, starting with 0x02 or 0x03 (so-called compressed public keys)
- 65 bytes, starting with 0x04

The byte arrays pushed here are 65 bytes, but do not start with 0x04.

Comment: This is `data store` tx https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35959/

Comment: Thank you Pieter and amaclin. I should have googled the transaction ID. I assume that it is not possible to spend these outputs as there is not corresponding private keys to enable the OP_CHECKMULTISIG to succeed.

And thank you for correcting my mistake in the original question.

Comment: @visualAd Indeed, it is unspendable.